# Openweathermap API call responding with wrong json

Tags: javascript, json, openweathermap

I am using the hourly forecast API call from Openweathe map to build a weather app. I can correctly fetch the URL for the call but the structure of the JSON that shows seems not to match the one provided as an example. I can't access `data.list` or either `data.sys` or `data.city.name`. While I can access `data.name`.

Here is the example JSON

```
{
cod: "200",
message: 0.0208,
cnt: 96,
list: [
{
dt: 1553709600,
main: {
temp: 286.44,
temp_min: 286.258,
temp_max: 286.44,
pressure: 1015.82,
sea_level: 1015.82,
grnd_level: 1002.193,
humidity: 100,
temp_kf: 0.18
},
weather: [
{
id: 500,
main: "Rain",
description: "light rain",
icon: "10d"
}
],
clouds: {
all: 86
},
wind: {
speed: 5.51,
deg: 202.816
},
rain: {
1h: 0.812
},
sys: {
pod: "d"
},
dt_txt: "2019-03-27 18:00:00"
},
...
],
city: {
id: 420006353,
name: "Mountain View",
coord: {
lat: 37.3894,
lon: -122.0833
},
country: "US"
}
}
```

and here is the code I use to manage the call

```
function call(city,country,zip) {
    let countryCode = list.getCode(country);
    let API;
    if (city!="" && country!="") {
        API = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+city.toLowerCase()+','+countryCode.toLowerCase()+'&APPID=1a9b84b61d1a8d6fdbb52fa2800ef894';
    }
    else if(country!="" && zip!=""){
        API ='http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/hourly?zip='+zip.toString()+','+countryCode.toLowerCase()+'&APPID=1a9b84b61d1a8d6fdbb52fa2800ef894';
    }

    else{
        alert("Please type your city or Zip code");
    }
    return API;
}




function getPlace() {
    let city = cityInput.value;
    let country = countryInput.value;
    let zip = zipInput.value;


    let APICall=call(city,country,zip);

    fetch(APICall).then(response=>{
        return response.json();
    }).then(data=>{
        let cityName= data.name;
        settler(cityName);
    })


}
```

I should be able to access `data.list` but 
`alert(data.list.lenght)` gives me an error saying that can not define length of undefined. Same for `alert(data.city.name)` that says that can not access name property of undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `weather` API docs correctly show the data you should expect for `weather` query:

https://openweathermap.org/current

Your `hourly` query should work if you hit the correct endpoint (`pro`) which your (exposed; you should fix that) API key is not valid for (AFAICT).

The [pricing page](https://openweathermap.org/price) indicates that `hourly` data is not available for free.